# change ImageView while true or in if loop?

Tags: java, android, xml, multithreading

I try to change my imageView every seconde, I think my code is correct but there is a probleme with thread or something like this, because I have a black screen when my activity start

```java
while(true)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 19;
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    String url = liste.getListe().get(rand).getImage();
    Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("got interrupted!");
    }
}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Use Runnable with postDelayed of 1 sec. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks

Comment: Thank, I think Runnable is good for me, but this is possible to use it white a while loop inside run()?

Comment: Do you even need a while loop? The Runnable will run every second. Just change the image within the Runnable

Answer (score 0):

Should liste.getListe( be with an e and not just list.getList() ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you block the `Main Thread` of your application with `Thread.sleep(1000)` and when `picasso` wants to load the image into the `imageView` it can't do it because the main thread handles views and it's blocked on that time. You could do it like so:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      int min = 0;
      int max = 19;
      Random r = new Random();
      int rand = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
      String url = liste.getListe().get(rand).getImage();
      Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView);
      handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
handler.post(runnableCode);
```